# What loan options are there for minors?

Tags: united-states, investing, loans, credit-score, credit

I'm not yet 18, but I have been studying business for quite a while, paper trading, investments, etc. at this point, I'd like to try my hand at building some credit and making some money, but I am still a minor, which makes this quite difficult. My parents have bad credit, and though it hasn't influenced my own business education, it means I can't loan on their names, and I can't back loans on their assets.

While I am also interested in what trading and investment options exist for minors, first things first, how can I take out a loan or line of credit as a minor without being weighed down by my parents' credit history?

Comment: You aren't planning to borrow money to invest it in the markets are you?

Comment: I was planning on corporate investment, a few well researched dollars

Comment: This question is distinct, by the way. For the other one, any solution to the car would apply. To this one, only ways of attaining actual funds, and not one specific product, would suffice. The idea was to find ways of getting both, hence two separate questions. As for the markets, even as a minor I can legally invest through a broker, which is fine to me so long as I hold final say

Comment: Try and edit the title to make it more distinct. It essentially asking the same question of how a minor can get a loan.